# ActiveMQ on Kuberenetes with Shared storage

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubernetes-pvc

I have existing applications built with Apache Camel and ActiveMQ. As part of migration to Kubernetes, what we are doing is moving the same services developed with Apache Camel to Kubernetes. I need to deploy ActiveMQ such that I do not lose the data in case one of the Pod dies.

What I am doing now is running a deployment with RelicaSet value to 2. This will start 2 pods and with a Service in front, I can serve any request while atleast 1 Pod is up. However, if one Pod dies, i do not want to lose the data. I want to implement something like a shared file system between the Pods. My environment is in AWS so I can use EBS. Can you suggest, how to achieve that.

Below is my deployment and service YAML.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: smp-activemq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smp-activemq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: smp-activemq
          image: dasdebde/activemq:5.15.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 61616
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smp-activemq
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: smp-activemq
  ports:
    - nodePort: 32191
      port: 61616
      targetPort: 61616
```

Comment: please format the yaml file properly :)

Comment: It looks ok to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) are valuable for applications that require stable, persistent storage. Deleting and/or scaling a StatefulSet down will not delete the volumes associated with the StatefulSet. This is done to ensure data safety. The "volumeClaimTemplates" part in yaml will provide stable storage using [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) provisioned by a PersistentVolume Provisioner.

In your case, StatefulSet file definition will look similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smp-activemq
  labels:
    app: smp-activemq
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: smp-activemq
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32191
    port: 61616
    name: smp-activemq
    targetPort: 61616

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: smp-activemq
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: smp-activemq
  serviceName: smp-activemq
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smp-activemq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: smp-activemq
        image: dasdebde/activemq:5.15.9
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 61616
          name: smp-activemq
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: <mount-path>
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "<storageclass-name>"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

That what you need to define is your StorageClass name and mountPath. I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In high-level terms, what you want is a **StatefulSet** instead of a Deployment for your ActiveMQ.  You are correct that you want "shared file system" -- in kubernetes this is expressed as a "**Persistent Volume**", which is made available to the pods in your StatefulSet using a "**Volume Mount**".

These are the things you need to look up.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to run everything in containers -- you get much more benefit from containers for stateless components than for stateful ones. AWS provides ActiveMQ as a managed service, called "Amazon MQ"

Comment: I understand that but in my case the environment will be running with a DMZ. So I am trying to avoid AWS services as much as I can

Comment: Let me try your suggestions. Thanks