# Active MQ in HA Shared Database (Master/Slave) on Kubernetes with StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubernetes-statefulset

I am in the process of deploying ActiveMQ 5.15 in HA on Kubernetes. Previously I was using a deployment and a `clusterIP` Service. And it was working fine. The master will boot up and the slave will wait for the lock to be acquired. If I delete the pod which is the master one, the slave picks up and becomes the master.

Now I want to try with `statefulset` basing myself on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289381/activemq-on-kuberenetes-with-shared-storage).
Deployment is done successfully and two pods were created with `id0` and `id1`. But what I noticed is that both pods were master. They were both started. I noticed also that two PVC were created `id0` and `id1` in the case of `Statefulset` compared to `deployment` which had only 1 PVC. Could that be the issue since it is no more a shared storage? Can we still achieve a master/slave setup with `Statefulset`?

Comment: It's not clear to me that HA configurations like this make sense in managed environments like K8s. The goal of HA is for the failure of one broker to result in the starting of another. However, in K8s if the ActiveMQ pod goes down then K8s will restart it providing essentially the same function as ActiveMQ's traditional HA configuration but with less configuration complexity and no idle pods waiting for a failure. Can you elaborate on the benefit(s) of a traditional HA configuration over K8s basic monitor/restart functionality?

Comment: very good point though. Since we are already using deployment with replica count 1, if the pod fails/terminates. Kubernetes will either restart or create a new one. Agree with you on this.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed also that two PVC were created id0 and id1 in the case of statefulset compared to deployment which had only 1 PVC. Could that be the issue since it is no more a shared storage?

You are right. When using k8s StatefulSets each Pod gets its own persistent storage (dedicated PVC and PV), and this persistent storage is not shared.

When a Pod gets terminated and is rescheduled on a different Node, the Kubernetes controller will ensure that the Pod is associated with the same PVC which will guarantee that the state is intact.

In your case, to achieve a master/slave setup, consider using a **shared network location / filesystem for persistent storage** like:

- [NFS storage](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner) for on-premise k8s cluster.
- [AWS EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/) for EKS.
- or [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume) for AKS.

Check the [complete list of PersistentVolume types currently supported by Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) (implemented as plugins).

Comment: so we cannot use statefulset then right? so we still use a deployment and a pvc.

Comment: @ashley, check this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/statefulset/README.md/), please. They create a simple StatefulSet and write from all pods to one file stored on EFS.